# Where is application.name_IS_UNDEFINED.log coming from?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, logging, microservices, logback

I have a Spring Boot microservice and whenever I start up this microservice, a file called application.name_IS_UNDEFINED.log is created and I don't know why this is happening. My microservice has a log file which is the name of the microservice .log. The only thing that is ever logged in this application.name_IS_UNDEFINED file is the following

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-10-08T09:24:09.498",
    "message": "HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.1.7.Final",
    "logger_name": "org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version",
    "thread_name": "background-preinit",
    "level": "INFO",
    "level_value": 20000,
    "application.environment": "local"
}
```

I don't see anything that would point to this file in my logback-spring.xml. Any ideas as to where this file is coming from?

Here is my logback config...

```
<!--  Spring variables  -->
<springProperty scope="context" name="application.name" source="spring.application.name"/>
<springProperty scope="context" name="application.environment" source="spring.profiles.active"/>
<springProperty scope="context" name="version" source="spring.application.version"/>

<springProfile name="local | dev | default">
    <!-- APPLICATION LOGS -->
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${application.name}.log</file>
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <includeMdc>false</includeMdc>
            <timeZone>America/Montreal</timeZone>
            <timestampPattern>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS</timestampPattern>

            <!--  Rename default fields name( ex. @timestamp to timestamp)  -->
            <fieldNames>
                <timestamp>timestamp</timestamp>
                <version>[ignore]</version>
            </fieldNames>

            <!--  Exceptions  -->
            <throwableConverter class="net.logstash.logback.stacktrace.ShortenedThrowableConverter">
                <maxDepthPerThrowable>30</maxDepthPerThrowable>
                <maxLength>2048</maxLength>
                <shortenedClassNameLength>60</shortenedClassNameLength>
                <exclude>sun\.reflect\..*\.invoke.*</exclude>
                <exclude>net\.sf\.cglib\.proxy\.MethodProxy\.invoke</exclude>
                <rootCauseFirst>true</rootCauseFirst>
                <inlineHash>true</inlineHash>
            </throwableConverter>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <!-- END APPLICATION LOGS -->

    <appender name="ASYNC" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LoggingEventAsyncDisruptorAppender">
        <waitStrategyType>sleeping</waitStrategyType>

        <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <withJansi>true</withJansi>
            <encoder>
                <pattern>[%date{ISO8601, America/Montreal}] %highlight([%-30.30thread]) %highlight([%40.40logger]) %highlight([%8.8level]): %msg %ex{full} %n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>

     <shutdownHook class="ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DelayingShutdownHook"/> 
</springProfile>

<springProfile name="${application.environment} &amp; !local &amp; !dev &amp; !default">
    <include file="/mnt/cfg/${application.name}-logback-spring.xml"/>
</springProfile>
```

Comment: Please also include your logback configuration.

Comment: This [line](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/v_1.2.6/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/subst/NodeToStringTransformer.java#L103) should be the reason for `application.name_IS_UNDEFINED.log`. But it will only create this file when it can't resolve `spring.application.name`, is there any thing special for this property?

Comment: odd that it can't resolve spring.application.name, given that I do have a log file with the application's name.

Comment: If you can provide a project reproducing the problem, I'm interested to debug what's happening. Currently I can't reproduce the problem to see both application.name_IS_UNDEFINED.log and microservice.log.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really provide a project.